# How to print a changed value of an array and revert it back to its previous value in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a script like this:

```js
var board = [
  [0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0]
];

function test() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
      if (board[i][j] == 0) {
          board[i][j] = 1;
          another(board);
          board[i][j] = 0;

      }
    }
  }
}

var anotherBoard = [];

function another(anotherBoard) {
  console.log(anotherBoard);
}
```

If I'm not mistaken the output was supposed to go through the array and change only one 0 to 1 each time without changing the value of the array 'board'.

But the output is:

```
[ [0, 0, 0]
, [0, 0, 0]
, [0, 0, 0]
] 
[ [0, 0, 0]
, [0, 0, 0]
, [0, 0, 0]
] 
[ [0, 0, 0]
, [0, 0, 0]
, [0, 0, 0]
] ...
```

How can I get an output like this:

```
[ [1, 0, 0]
, [0, 0, 0]
, [0, 0, 0]
]
[ [0, 1, 0]
, [0, 0, 0]
, [0, 0, 0]
] 
[ [0, 0, 1]
, [0, 0, 0]
, [0, 0, 0]
]
...
```

Comment: It seems to make the desired output?

Comment: @kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze in my case it doesn't. I'm using the onclick function with a button to call the function. Is that what it might be making the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code by calling `test()`. I got the folllowing output:

[image]

So looks like it does what you want. You should watch out the context in which you're executing the code:

- check if you call the right `test()`
- is `console.log()` modified by the user?
- change `var` with `let`; I don't recommend ever using `var` until you need it

From what you said on how you get the output, I don't see the newlines, so something might be wrong with `console.log()`, or you're calling something else

Bonus: try to format your code better, it really makes a difference when you're sharing it

Comment: I have nothing other than those codes in my whole script. I'm using the onclick function with a button to call the function. Is that what it might be making the problem?

Comment: Can't yet figure out. You should share a html snippet containing all the relevant code (including the button), and prove that it still doesn't work. This way I can reproduce the problem and look for a solution

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for.

```js
let boards = []

function addBoard() {
  console.log('adding a board')
  let onepos = boards.length < 3 ? boards.length : boards.length % 3,
    tmp = [
      [],
      [],
      []
    ]
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
      if (i === 0 && j === onepos) tmp[i][j] = 1;
      else tmp[i][j] = 0
    }
  }
  boards.push(tmp)
}

addBoard()
addBoard()
addBoard()
console.log(boards);
```